# Installing 16.04 from usb how long does it take

Tags: 16.04, usb, plymouth

Installed Ubuntu from USB on a win 10 laptop stuck on the black screen after restart after installation keeps reading 
NMI watchdog bug soft lockup -Cpu1# stuck for 22s ! plymouthd 6738 
NMI watchdog bug soft lockup -Cpu1# stuck for 23s ! plymouthd 6738
Info rcu_sched self-detected stall on cpu

Then this with one with different numbering on each, each time

1-...: (37505245 ticks this GP) idle=cab/1400000000001/0 softirq=48786 fqs=3794747
(T=3795  jiffies g=3xxx c= xxx q= xxxx)

Has been installing about 5hours what is the next step of action ,and help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What brand/model system? Often extra boot paramters are required, depending on configuration. I install on my desktop  from HDD sdb to SSD sda in about 10 Min. From SSD to HDD in about 15 min. But SSD to flash drive is still about 30 to 45 min.

Comment: See here https://askubuntu.com/questions/976542/lubuntu-16-04-gets-stuck-at-shutdown-nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu1-stuck/989707#989707